# how to add 3d effect on imageview

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, effect

how to add shadow effect on imageview like this shreen shot

[image: images]

how do add this type 3d effect i imageview any idea????

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/test_button_image"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="200dp"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:background="@drawable/border6"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Just creating an imageView is not actually close to what you want.

Answer (score 8):

#### First Step

Create a drawable like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item><layer-list>
        <item android:left="3dp" android:top="3dp"><shape>
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#E2E2E2" android:startColor="#BABABA" />
            <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#BABABA" />

            <corners android:radius="2dp" />

            <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="2dp" />
        </shape></item>
    </layer-list></item>
</selector>
```

#### Second Step

Set it as background of `ImageView`

```
<ImageView 
    ..
    android:background="@drawable/selected_image_shadow" >
</ImageView>
```

**Output**

[image]

Left image is without shadow and right image is with shadow.

**Note**

You need to modify code as per your requirement. This is sample demo with my requirement.

**Edit**

Use following code to apply reflection effect on image.

```
public static Bitmap applyReflection(Bitmap originalImage) {
    // gap space between original and reflected
    final int reflectionGap = 4;
    // get image size
    int width = originalImage.getWidth();
    int height = originalImage.getHeight();

    // this will not scale but will flip on the Y axis
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.preScale(1, -1);

    // create a Bitmap with the flip matrix applied to it.
    // we only want the bottom half of the image
    Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0,
            height / 2, width, height / 2, matrix, false);

    // create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit reflection
    Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,
            (height + height / 2), Config.ARGB_8888);

    // create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for
    // the image plus gap plus reflection
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
    // draw in the original image
    canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
    // draw in the gap
    Paint defaultPaint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap, defaultPaint);
    // draw in the reflection
    canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage, 0, height + reflectionGap, null);

    // create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the reflection
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0,
            originalImage.getHeight(), 0, bitmapWithReflection.getHeight()
                    + reflectionGap, 0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff, TileMode.CLAMP);
    // set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
    paint.setShader(shader);
    // set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
    // draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient
    canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, bitmapWithReflection.getHeight()
            + reflectionGap, paint);

    return bitmapWithReflection;
}
```

Comment: I tried in one of my application. How it has no any effect..? Please see my edited output..

Comment: i dont want gray e shadow i want mirror shadow on bottom like my screenshot

Answer (score 2):

You can check this [open source project on coverflow](https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/), you might get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for mirror reflection on imageview

```
public Bitmap getRefelection(Bitmap image) {

// The gap we want between the reflection and the original image

final int reflectionGap = 0;

// Get your bitmap from drawable folder

Bitmap originalImage = image;

int width = originalImage.getWidth();
int height = originalImage.getHeight();

// This will not scale but will flip on the Y axis

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.preScale(1, -1);

/*Create a Bitmap with the flip matix applied to it.
We only want the bottom half of the image*/

Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0,
height / 2, width, height / 2, matrix, false);

// Create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit reflection

Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,(height + height /                  2), Config.ARGB_8888);

// Create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for
// the image plus gap plus reflection

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);

// Draw in the original image

canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);

//Draw the reflection Image

canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage, 0, height + reflectionGap, null);

// Create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the reflection

Paint paint = new Paint();
LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0,
originalImage.getHeight(), 0, bitmapWithReflection.getHeight()
+ reflectionGap, 0x99ffffff, 0x00ffffff, TileMode.CLAMP);

// Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)

paint.setShader(shader);

// Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));

// Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient

canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, bitmapWithReflection.getHeight()
+ reflectionGap, paint);
if(originalImage!=null && originalImage.isRecycled()){
originalImage.recycle();
originalImage=null;
}
if(reflectionImage!=null && reflectionImage.isRecycled()){
reflectionImage.recycle();
reflectionImage=null;
}
return bitmapWithReflection;
}
}
```